# filtering a specific data from the fetched data

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to filter a specific data from a database and return it to the page.
my strategy was use httpClient get method in the service and only get
specific data. how I can handle the filtering

so far I can get all the data included in a testurl but I dont know how to filter the specific ones

data.json

```
[
    {"allOrders":21},
    {"pendingConfirmOrders":14},
    {"pendingPaymentOrders":8}
]
```

order-history.component.ts

```
import { orderHistoryService } from './../../infrastructure/services/order-history.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-order-history-page',
  templateUrl: './order-history-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order-history-page.component.scss']
})
export class OrderHistoryPageComponent implements OnInit {
orderHistory:any;
confirmOrder;
  constructor(private orderService:orderHistoryService) {
    this.orderService.getOrderHistory().subscribe((response:any)=>{
      this.orderHistory = response;
    });
   }
  _orderHistory(){
    console.log(this.orderHistory);
  }
  _pendingConformation(){
    this.confirmOrder=this.orderHistory.filter(orders=> this.orderHistory
      .includes(this.confirmOrder));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}



orderService.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AppSettings } from '../../app.setting';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class orderHistoryService {
    private testUrl='../../../assets/data/orders.json';
//   _baseUrl = AppSettings.BACKEND2_SUBSCRIBE_BASE;
  constructor(private _apiService: ApiService, private _http: HttpClient) { }
  getOrderHistory():Observable<any>{
    return this._http.get<any>(this.testUrl);
    //  const endpoint = `${AppSettings.SERVER_API}`//endpoint;
    //  return this._http.get(endpoint);
  }
  /**
 * THIS METHOD GET The history of orders
 */
}
```

the functions I wrote returns an empty array

Comment: *I dont know how to filter the specific ones* -- What are the conditions for your filter?

Comment: I hope I can be clear. I want to return allOrders,pendingConfirmOrders and pendingPaymentOrders values seperately not all toghter

Comment: Sorry; still unclear, well at-least for me. Could you give an example of the output you are expecting?

Comment: sure I want something like this :
history of your orders : 21
orders that need conformation: 14
orders that need payment:8
for this mattter I need to get the value of each item in data.json separately

Comment: @Alirezatk I still can't understand what you're asking. Show us a concrete example of the JSON returned by your API, and the precise output that you want from that input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `data.json` is an **array** of JSON objects, you will need to include the index of the array when you create JavaScript variables to hold the data from your API response.

Creating the variables should look something like this:

```
allOrders = orderHistory[0].allOrders;
pendingConfirmOrders = orderHistory[1].pendingConfirmOrders;
pendingPaymentOrders = orderHistory[2].pendingPaymentOrders;
```

This is only going to work if you know the structure of `data.json` will not change. If you have control over the API, I would recommend getting rid of the array and making the output look something like this:

```
{
"allOrders":21,
"pendingConfirmOrders":14,
"pendingPaymentOrders":8
}
```

This way, you would be able to omit the array index and access the data as you mentioned in your comment above - using `orderHistory.pendingConfirmOrders;`